# An Integration about error function

Tags: integration

An integration which Mathematica gives the result:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda k^2}}{a+b k^2}\mathrm{d}k
= \frac{e^{\frac{a\lambda}{b}}\pi}{2\sqrt{ab}}\mathrm{Erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a\lambda}{b}} \right)
$$
where
$$
\mathrm{Erfc}(x) =  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$
I want to know how to calculate it without Mathematica!

This is the result Mathematica gives:
[image]

PS:

I encounter this problem when I calculate a Green's function in this paper(PRA 99,012701(2019) Equation (3)).

I ask my supervisor for advice, he told me that I don't need to care about how to calculate it when Mathematica gives results. But, I do not feel at ease use a result that I can not get it by myself.

Please forgive my poor English. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the integral you wish to calculate as 
$$
I(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{1}{2b}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda k^2}}{k^2+\mu}dk,
$$
with $\mu=\frac{a}{b}$. We use the identity 
$$
e^{\lambda\mu}\int^{\infty}_{\lambda}e^{-t(k^2 + \mu)}dt= \frac{e^{-\lambda k^2}}{k^2 + \mu}
$$ 
and write the integral $I(\lambda,\mu)$ as
$$
I(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{e^{\lambda\mu}}{2b}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{\lambda}e^{-t(k^2 + \mu)}dtdk,
$$
we integrate over $k$ and get
$$
I(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{e^{\lambda\mu}\sqrt{\pi}}{2b}\int^{\infty}_{\lambda}\frac{e^{-t \mu}}{\sqrt{t}}dt.
$$
where this last integral is just the error function. To this we do define the new variable $t=x^2/\mu$ and finally obtain
$$
I(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{e^{\lambda\mu}\pi}{2b\sqrt{\mu}}\int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda a}{b}}}e^{-  x^{2}}dx=\frac{e^{\lambda\mu}\pi}{2b\sqrt{\mu}} Erfc\left( \sqrt{\frac{\lambda a}{b}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try differentiating with respect to $\lambda$. That will give you an easy integral on the left hand side, and the derivative of Erfc with respect to irs argument on the right hand side is a gaussian. Then integrate up both sides using the easily evaluated value when $\lambda=0$ to fix the additive constant that was lost when differentiating.

To be more specific (I set $a=b=1$ for laziness). If
$$
I(\lambda)= \int_o^\infty\frac{e^{-\lambda k^2}}{1+k^2} dk
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dI}{d\lambda}+I = \frac {c}{\sqrt \lambda}
$$
where $c$ is $\int_0^\infty e^{- k^2}dk=\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: If you differentiate with respect to $\lambda$, the integral is not a Gaussian and is still quite complicated.

Comment: @lakehal I will edit to make clear what I mean.

Comment: I find it easier if one integrate instead of differentiating, but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @lakehal Agreed. Your method is quicker!

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But how to get the result form this differential equation? I have no idea about this differential equation.

Comment: @ZKW  You don't have to solve it. Just check that your solution satisfies the equation and the initial condition at $\lambda=0$.